# Java - isntantiate with reflection does not work

Tags: java, reflection, instantiation

**Why this one works:**

```
NormalChair nc = new NormalChair("a", 4);
    System.out.println(nc.getName());
```

Outputs: a

And this one does not:

```
Object nc_ref = Class.forName("test.NormalChair").getConstructor(String.class, Integer.class).newInstance("a",4);
Method m_get = nc_ref.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getName");
System.out.println(m_get.invoke(nc_ref));
```

I get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: test.NormalChair.<init>(java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2800)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1708)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:37)
```

Comment: Given the answers below, do you mind posting the code of the constructor? This will ensure that we have a complete question with reasonable answers and that in turn might be very useful for someone googling for a similar problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the constructor I can't be sure but I suspect you want `int.class`, not `Integer.class`. (Yes, that's legal!)

```
Object nc_ref = Class.forName("test.NormalChair").getConstructor(
    String.class, int.class).newInstance("a", 4);
```

Comment: Changing to int.class, gives this error now:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: test.NormalChair.getName()
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:1994)
 at test.Test.main(Test.java:39)`

Comment: @Andrius If `getName()` is inherited from a parent class, you must use `getMethod` rather than `getDeclaredMethod` -- getDeclaredMethod doesn't search the parent class.

Comment: Oh thanks, I just figured that now:). Will choose your answer though.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the constructor `NormalChair("a", 4)` take `String` and `int` as input parameters, right?

In that case, I think the correct call is `getConstructor(String.class, int.class)`

The difference is `int.class` not `Integer.class`

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Found what was wrong. It seems I need to use `getMethod()`, not `getDeclaredMethod()`, because it didn't see that method even thought it was declared as public. Maybe because it inherits method from parent class? Correct me if I'm wrong.